# Pandas: calculating values with .where() leaves rows blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the following in an attempt to selectively apply calculations to parts of a dataframe. It seems as though when the second statement is run, the values from the first statement are removed.

```
df5['AbsWindVAspect'] = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'].where(df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] <= 180)
df5['AbsWindVAspect'] = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect2'].where(df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] > 180)
```

Is there a different approach I should be using here to identifying rows that meet a certain criteria, performing the calculation, then changing to other rows with new criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `where` with `other` option:

```
df5['AbsWindVAspect'] = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'].where(df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] <= 180, 
                                                       df5['tmpAbsWindAspect2'])
```

Or use `np.where` for somewhat more readable code:

```
df5['AbsWindVAspect'] = np.where(df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] <= 180,
                                 df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'],
                                 df5['tmpAbsWindAspect2']
                                )
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example. Is there something else I should be trying, however? Sometimes I might have 4 or 5 conditions where I'd like to write out a custom formula based on the 'where' clause. .

Comment: @anakaine that's the job for [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does .select need to be joined back?

Comment: Join back in what sense? `df['new_col'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [value1, value2], default_value)`?

Comment: I'm clearly not sure what I'm asking. Thanks for your time today :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `np.select`

```
cond1 = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] <= 180
cond2 = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1'] > 180

v1 = df5['tmpAbsWindAspect1']
v2=df5['tmpAbsWindAspect2']

df['AbsWindVAspect'] = np.select([cond1,cond2],[v1,v2])
```

Comment: Thanks Beny, I'll give that a try.